# Parser in QT for json

Tags: c++, json, qt, qt5, qtcore

I need to edit my parser code in C++ with QT. I got inspired by someone. I got an issue, he parses only the half of my .json file.

this is my code :

```
    #include <QJsonArray>
    #include "mainwindow.h"
    #include <QApplication>
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <QPushButton>
    #include <QFile>
    #include <QDebug>
    #include <QJsonDocument>
    #include <QJsonObject>
    #include <QTranslator>
    #include "parcer_js.h"
    #include <iostream>
    #include <QList>
    #include <QString>
    #include <string>
    #include <parcer_js.h>
    #include <Mail.hpp>
    #include <QDate>

void Parcer::parcerJs()
{
      QString val;
      QFile file;
      file.setFileName("jstest.json");

      file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly | QIODevice::Text);
      val = file.readAll();
      file.close();

      QJsonDocument d = QJsonDocument::fromJson(val.toUtf8());
      ParcerByfile(d);
}

void Parcer::ParcerByfile(QJsonDocument d)
{
      QJsonObject sett2 = d.object();
      qWarning() << sett2;

      QJsonValue value = sett2.value(QString("123")); // Problem !!! 
      QJsonObject item = value.toObject();

      QJsonValue subFrom = item["from"];
      qWarning() << subFrom.toString();

      QJsonArray strTo = item["to"].toArray();
      qWarning() << strTo[0].toString();
      qWarning() << strTo[1].toString();
}
```

This is the .json code :

```
{
    "123": {
        "from": "magellan.dunord@antarctica.com",
        "to": [
            "lol@hotmail.fr",
            "pipo@antartica-base.com"
        ],
        "cc": [
            "johndoe@il2.fr",
            "gordonfreeman@antarctica.com"
        ],
        "cci": [
            "missepitech@antarctica.com"
        ],
        "obj": "trolol > all",
        "contenu": "Hello  3301  Word ! !",
        "date": "21-1-1993",
        "domaine": "antartica-base.com",
        "state": "0",
        "pseudo_f": "Jd"
    },
    "456": {
        "from": "pipo@antarctica.com",
        "to": [
            "lol@hotmail.fr",
            "pipo@antartica-base.com"
        ],
        "cc": [
            "johndoe@flavicon.fr",
            "gordonfreeman@qwerty.fr"
        ],
        "cci": [
            "missepitech@antarctica.com"
        ],
        "obj": "3301 > all",
        "contenu": "Hello 3301 Word ! !",
        "date": "21-12-1993",
        "domaine": "antartica-base.com",
        "state": "0",
        "pseudo_f": "Jd"
    }
}
```

The problem is in this line :

```
QJsonValue value = sett2.value(QString("123"));
```

I need to find first the ID behind this ": {" and I will create a system

because my code only parses "123" part in my .json file.
I want to know how I can parse "123" and "456" into an item or a list. Because normally I do not know what would be the ID.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done by obtaining all the keys and then you can use the first method on the returned QStringList.

See the [documentation](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qjsonobject.html#keys) for details.

Therefore, you would be writing something like this:

```
QJsonValue value = sett2.value(sett2.keys().first()); // NO Problem !!!
```

You could likely use the [begin iterator](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qjsonobject.html#begin) as well as follows:

```
QJsonValue value = sett2.begin().value();
```

Here is the full sample project for reference:

#### main.json

```
{
    "123": {
        "from": "magellan.dunord@antartica-base.com",
        "to": [
            "lol@hotmail.fr",
            "pipo@antartica-base.com"
        ],
        "cc": [
            "johndoe@antartica-base.com",
            "gordonfreeman@antartica-base.com"
        ],
        "cci": [
            "missepitech@antartica-base.com"
        ],
        "obj": "EpiMTP2017 > all",
        "contenu": "Hello  3301  Word ! !",
        "date": "21-12-1993",
        "domaine": "antartica-base.com",
        "state": "0",
        "pseudo_f": "Jd"
    },
    "456": {
        "from": "laray.croft@antartica-base.com",
        "to": [
            "lol@hotmail.fr",
            "pipo@antartica-base.com"
        ],
        "cc": [
            "johndoe@antartica-base.com",
            "gordonfreeman@antartica-base.com"
        ],
        "cci": [
            "missepitech@antartica-base.com"
        ],
        "obj": "EpiMTP2017 > all",
        "contenu": "Hello 3301 Word ! !",
        "date": "21-12-1993",
        "domaine": "antartica-base.com",
        "state": "0",
        "pseudo_f": "Jd"
    }
}
```

#### main.pro

```
TEMPLATE = app
TARGET = main
QT = core
SOURCES += main.cpp
```

#### main.cpp

```
#include <QFile>
#include <QByteArray>
#include <QJsonDocument>
#include <QJsonObject>
#include <QDebug>

int main()
{
    QFile file("main.json");
    file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly | QIODevice::Text);
    QByteArray jsonData = file.readAll();
    file.close();

    QJsonDocument d = QJsonDocument::fromJson(jsonData);
    QJsonObject sett2 = d.object();

    QJsonValue value = sett2.begin().value();
    QJsonValue value2 = sett2.value(sett2.keys().first());
    qDebug() << value;
    qDebug() << " =========== ";
    qDebug() << value2;
    return 0;
}
```

#### Build and Run

```
qmake && make && ./main
```

#### Output

```
QJsonValue(object, QJsonObject({"cc": ["johndoe@antartica-base.com","gordonfreeman@antartica-base.com"],"cci": ["missepitech@antartica-base.com"],"contenu": "Hello  3301  Word ! !","date": "21-12-1993","domaine": "antartica-base.com","from": "magellan.dunord@antartica-base.com","obj": "EpiMTP2017 > all","pseudo_f": "Jd","state": "0","to": ["lol@hotmail.fr","pipo@antartica-base.com"]}) ) 
===========  
QJsonValue(object, QJsonObject({"cc": ["johndoe@antartica-base.com","gordonfreeman@antartica-base.com"],"cci": ["missepitech@antartica-base.com"],"contenu": "Hello  3301  Word ! !","date": "21-12-1993","domaine": "antartica-base.com","from": "magellan.dunord@antartica-base.com","obj": "EpiMTP2017 > all","pseudo_f": "Jd","state": "0","to": ["lol@hotmail.fr","pipo@antartica-base.com"]}) )
```

Comment: Thanks very much for your answer. But my principal problem is to know how I can get this keys ? 

Maybe using some conditions after all this two characters "}," ?

Comment: That is what the answer contains. You use the same concept for any embedded json object. Other than that, I would not understand why you would need to create a list.